# Enable versioning Document Library

Tags: document-library, client-object-model

i am trying to enable versioning on a ducument library using the client object model my code currently is as follows when i create the document library.

```
            ClientContext clientContext = getClientContext();
        try
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            ListCollection listCol = web.Lists;
            ListCreationInformation lci = new ListCreationInformation();
            lci.Title = DocLib;
            lci.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary;
            List documentLibrary = listCol.Add(lci);
            documentLibrary.EnableVersioning = true;
            documentLibrary.EnableMinorVersions = true;
            documentLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
            clientContext.Load(listCol);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("doclibCreated created");
            return documentLibrary;
        }
        catch (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
```

but these settings are not persisted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call Update() to apply document library properties:

```
.
.
documentLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

documentLibrary.Update();   <---- ADDED

clientContext.Load(listCol);
.
.
```

Comment: ah yes that makes sense thatnks alot :)